# Is it possible to call WSDL method just by calling some url from browser?

Tags: url, browser, wsdl, call

Is it possible to call WSDL (bacikHTTPbinding) method just by calling some url from browser?

Answer (score 6):

According to this:  http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/java/how-to-call-web-service-from-browser

You can by calling replacing

`../SomeService?wsdl`

with

`../SomeService/methodName?paramName=value`

However that doesn't work with xfire, the website states so. (website uses Axis2)